# How do I select the runtime in bazel for Python and pip?

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-python

I'm trying to build an app on Ubuntu 20.04, where python3 points to Python3.8, and I'm building aganist Python3.6

I have the following runtime in the same directory of WORKSPACE.

```
$ cat BUILD.bazel 
py_runtime(
    name = "python3.6",
    interpreter_path = "/usr/bin/python3.6",
)
```

I tried to build the app by running the following and bazel still points to python3 which is python3.8

```
bazelisk build company/app_api:app --python_top=//:python3.6
```

I also tried the deprecated option and didn't work either.

```
bazelisk build company/app_api:app --python_path=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

This is the error I get:

```
...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--isolated', 'wheel', '-r', '/source_code/src/python/third_party/requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
...
```

pip is trying to install a package that works only with python3.6, and that's why it's returning a non zero exist code.

How do I force bazel to use a custom python interpreter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`py_runtime` usually must be used with `py_runtime_pair` and `toolchain` . See [the example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/master/docs/python.md) in the `py_runtime_pair` documentation. That example, slightly modified to apply to the OP would look like:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/python:toolchain.bzl", "py_runtime_pair")

py_runtime(
    name = "python3.6",
    interpreter_path = "/usr/bin/python3.6",
    python_version = "PY3",   
)

py_runtime_pair(
    name = "py3.6",
    py3_runtime = ":python3.6",
)

toolchain(
    name = "py3-tc",
    toolchain = ":py3.6",
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/python:toolchain_type",
)
```

Then one can use the new toolchain by placing `register_toolchains("//path/to/python3:py3-tc")` in the `WORKSPACE` file or passing the `--extra_toolchains //path/to/python3:py3-tc` command line flag.

Add python_interpreter to pip_install in WORKSPACE.

```
pip_install(
    requirements = "//third_party:requirements.txt",
    python_interpreter = 'python3.6'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pip support from a [bazelbuild/rules_python](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python), then there is no probably a clean way to do this like reusing a python interpreter from the toolchain. [`python3` is hardcoded in the rule definition](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/53ba6cbbb820d88ab6df966e4f558525fe82eb93/python/pip_install/pip_repository.bzl#L135)

Comment: It isn't hardcoded. This is the default value for the `version` variable. And as described in the [Bazel docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html#py_runtime) and [docs of python rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/master/docs/python.md) you can redefine the interpreter version.

Answer (score 0):

Following to the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html#py_runtime_example) following example should work with `python` version `3.6.0`. I think `bazel` just doesn't follow symlinks and falls back to a system-default version of `python`.

```
py_runtime(
    name = "python-3.6.0",
    interpreter_path = "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/python",
)
```

You can also redefine python toolchain as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67512752/9038646).