# Bazel build fails with msg "env: python: No such file or directory" (macOS Monterey)

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, bazel, macos-monterey

I am new to python world and I have followed a few articles to set python on my system. I need python to build my project through bazel.

When I build my project on **local**, I get the following error. Please note, I am able to build the project successfully on server so issue is not related to code.

```
env: python: No such file or directory
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.708s, Critical Path: 1.09s
INFO: 7 processes: 4 darwin-sandbox, 3 worker.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Please **HELP ME** to solve this issue with my build failure.

I tried to solve this by applying the solutions online but all in vain.
I have removed my complete python env and have re-configured it as well but that did not work for me either.

**This is my system configuration:**

> Python version in env is: Python 3.9.12 but it still says "env: python: No such file or directory" in the above error.

```
└─(13:59:50)──> /usr/bin/env python --version    
Python 3.9.12
```

> If I fire **/usr/bin/python3 --version** I get **Python 3.8.9** as output

```
└─(13:47:35)──> /usr/bin/python3 --version                   
Python 3.8.9
```

But when `cd` into the `/usr/bin/` and I fire `python3 --version` command I get **Python 3.9.12** as output.

```
┌─(/usr/bin)──────────────────────────────────────────
└─(13:56:29)──> pwd                                                      
/usr/bin
┌─(/usr/bin)──────────────────────────────────────────
└─(13:56:32)──> python3 --version                                        
Python 3.9.12
```

Also, both `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python3` point to `Python 3.9.12`.

```
┌─(/usr/bin)──────────────────────────────────────────
└─(13:56:41)──> /usr/local/bin/python --version       
Python 3.9.12
┌─(/usr/bin)──────────────────────────────────────────
└─(13:57:46)──> /usr/local/bin/python3 --version      
Python 3.9.12
```

Answer (score 10):

I am having the same issue.  Here is what I found.
Bazel builds often use `py_binary` tools, which are launched with a shell script that has the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` (in versions prior to 5).  But it also launches them inside a subshell that clears the `PATH` environment variable. `(exec env - ...)`.

This means that there must be a `python` on the system path.  Modifying your `PATH` won't help nor will using something like `pyenv`. To see which python is being used, run `(exec env - python)`.  In macOS 12.3, Apple removed `/usr/bin/python`. so this fails and prints `env: python: No such file or directory`.

I haven't found any way to fix this, since Apple also does not let you modify `/usr/bin` to add a symlink to `python3` even as root (due to System Integrity Protection).

This is fixed in Bazel 5, but I am not able to upgrade to that since I need to be able to make updates on an older project that has libraries that require Bazel < 4.

Note that Github macOS runners are still on macOS 11.  That may be why your project still builds on your server.

I am blocked at this point.  I think I either need to find a way to add `python` to the system `PATH` (working around SIP), or I need to back-port some changes from Bazel 5 to Bazel 3 and use a custom version of Bazel.  Or I need to do all development and debugging on an older version of macOS.

Comment: I was able to work around this by getting my project to work with Bazel 4 and using the `py_runtime` approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67512066/how-do-i-select-the-runtime-in-bazel-for-python-and-pip

Answer (score 2):

You are right about your analysis @[Matthew Self](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6179853/matthew-self). The symlink cannot be create due to MacOS's SIP. Even after disabling it you cannot create a symlink in `/usr/bin/...` since it is read-only.

More info on this here - [Cannot create a symlink inside of /usr/bin even as sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730549/cannot-create-a-symlink-inside-of-usr-bin-even-as-sudo)

---

Now I am also having a similar issue while building a bazel target that is by default using `/usr/bin/python` for running any python files. Since my bazel verison is 3.7.1, so it is giving the similar error as yours after updating the OS Monterery.

But using `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python` solved my issue as it created a symlink in `/usr/local/bin/...` instead of `/usr/bin/...` and surprisingly bazel picked up this PATH of python by deafault.

May be because `/usr/local/bin` will be listed before `/usr/bin`, hence it was taking precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem. The approach I used is to hack bazel 4.1.0.

First, check out the bazel 4.1.0 source

By modifying the file:
`src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/python/python_stub_template.txt`

change the first line

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

into

`#!/usr/bin/env /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

You can specify the python2 path here.

Last, you build the modified bazel in command line:

`$ bazel build //src:bazel`

You can get a modified version of bazel. By using this bazel instead of original one, the problem is solved.